# If x is correlated with y, is there formula to use that alone to write x as a function of y, or to relate the two variables?

Tags: regression, correlation, random-variable

for example, if $\text{corr}(x,y)\not=0$, can you always decompose $x$ to be:
$x={\text{cov}(x,y)/\text{var}(x)} + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is just all other remaining parts of $x$ uncorrelated with $y$? (using the regression formula)

Also, is there a way to do this with a third variable: so say Y is correlated with X, and Z is correlated with Y, then can I relate Z to X?

Comment: Two things: (1) you can use the decomposition also when the correlation is equal to zero; (2) you forgot to multiply the cov/var by $y$.

Comment: ok thank for you the answer. so that decomposition from regression is just true of any two random variables?